# Double vertice for the "Screw" modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers, screw-modifier

I'm trying to create a screw bottle. To a simple figure (6 vertices) I apply the “**Screw**” modifier.

[image]

At the junction of the turns, double vertices are formed.

[image]

Enabling the "*Automerge*" mode and reducing the "*Merge*" parameter on the modifier to *0.001 m* does not give any results. How can I get rid of double vertices? Blender version 3.6.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't count on a *Merge* operation as long as the topology is virtual, i.e. as long as you haven't applied the *Screw* modifier. But if you want to keep the modifier unapplied you can put a *Weld* modifier below the *Screw* modifier, it will act like a *Merge > By Distance*.

Comment: The fact of the matter is that I am applying the “Screw” modifier. I'll try the "Weld" modifier now.

Comment: OK. Thank you! "Weld" modifier helped me.

Comment: The Weld modifier is useful if you want to stay non-destructive (i.e. you want to keep the modifiers unapplied). If you apply the modifier, make sure that the scale of your object is applied, then in Edit mode select all, M > Merge by Distance, and in the Operator Box increase the Merge Distance until the vertices merge